# Cakephp AppError file under Lib folder not getting included

Tags: php, cakephp

I am using cakephp 2.2

I have created a class AppError under app/Lib folder.
when i am including it under bootstrap file I am not able to use its function. 
It seem it is not included

I used
App::uses('AppError','Lib')

Any help will b appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App/lib directory is mostly used to override all the core functionality of cakePHP ([refer here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/app.html)), you can create a component and use it in your case.

Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.... It is working fine now... It was included but not showing any effect.... After doing changes in core.php it start working